# Conditional replacement of values in data frame column based off multiple other columns - R

Tags: r, dataframe

My data frame looks like this

```
> tornado_frame
         tornado_names Level      value
1     node per cluster   low  -34.72222
2          TB per node   low  -52.08333
3  expense per cluster   low -104.16667
4             Total TB   low  -62.50000
5  revenue per cluster   low  -52.08333
6     node per cluster  high   20.83333
7          TB per node  high   41.66667
8  expense per cluster  high   52.08333
9             Total TB  high  145.83333
10 revenue per cluster  high  156.25000
```

I want the table to transform into this

```
> tornado_frame
         tornado_names Level      value
1     node per cluster   low   34.72222
2          TB per node   low   52.08333
3  expense per cluster   low  104.16667
4             Total TB   low  -62.50000
5  revenue per cluster   low  -52.08333
6     node per cluster  high  -20.83333
7          TB per node  high  -41.66667
8  expense per cluster  high  -52.08333
9             Total TB  high  145.83333
10 revenue per cluster  high  156.25000
```

Where the negative sign in "value" changes if its absolute value is greater than that of the "high" Level column and of the same tornado_name column.

I tried a few nested if's but that got messy for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my data:

```
> dput(tornado_frame)
structure(list(tornado_names = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("expense per cluster", "node per cluster", 
"revenue per cluster", "TB per node", "Total TB"), class = "factor"), 
    Level = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("high", "low"), class = "factor"), value = c(34.72222, 
    52.08333, 104.16667, -62.5, -52.08333, -20.83333, -41.66667, 
    -52.08333, 145.83333, 156.25)), .Names = c("tornado_names", 
"Level", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value := if(diff(abs(value)) < 0) value * -1,
                                            by = tornado_names]
df
#           tornado_names Level     value
#  1:    node per cluster   low  34.72222
#  2:         TB per node   low  52.08333
#  3: expense per cluster   low 104.16667
#  4:            Total TB   low -62.50000
#  5: revenue per cluster   low -52.08333
#  6:    node per cluster  high -20.83333
#  7:         TB per node  high -41.66667
#  8: expense per cluster  high -52.08333
#  9:            Total TB  high 145.83333
# 10: revenue per cluster  high 156.25000
```

This will check your condition per `tornado_names` and only change the sign for the values within the groups where the condition is satisfied.

Comment: what if I wanted to add a second condition within that if statement to check a condition in another data frame's column @david

Comment: So just add it with an `&` like `if(cond1 & cond2)`

Comment: Is there a way I can force the if statement to look at all elements of cond2's data frame (I'm getting the "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used") and I'd prefer not to have to switch to ifelse

Comment: Yes you can do stuff like `if(value[1] > 1)` or similar stuff. It's hard to tell what is your situation exactly.